# Interactions between Onscreen and Offscreen rendering in Qt5 with QOpenGL\* classes

Tags: opengl, qt5

#### Objective:

To make some **onscreen** and **offscreen** rendering via Qt5 OpenGL framework, such that the resources can be easily shared between both rendering parts. Specifically,

- the rendering work is done through the **offscreen** part (the framebuffer might be larger than the display screen);
- the results of the **offscreen** rendering can be displayed in multiple **onscreen** parts (say, `QOpenGLWidget`s) under different settings, e.g. different sizes, for simplicity;
- the results of the **offscreen** rendering can also be extracted from GPU and saved into a `QImage` or `cv::Mat` object;
- the above tasks can be executed asynchronously (doing the second offscreen rendering, while displaying or extracting the first offscreen result).

#### Current solution:

Since I don't know how to share resources between both parts, the actual rendering work are done redundantly in both parts in my current solution:

The **onscreen** part:

- A `QMainWindow` containing multiple `QOpenGLWidget` (subclass of `QOpenGLWidget`) objects;

The **offscreen** part:

- A custom class involving members of `QOffscreenSurface`, `QOpenGLContext`, and `QOpenGLFramebufferObject` pointers, as well as a `QOpenGLFunctions` pointer to invoke OpenGL functions do the actual rendering work, much similar to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323749/easiest-way-for-offscreen-rendering-with-qopenglwidget).

The actual renderer:

- As the reason above, the actual rendering work is extracted into a seperated class and both parts (**onscreen** and **offscreen**) have its handle.

#### Questions:

There are two `QOpenGLContext`s:

- When doing the **offscreen** work in a background thread (for asynchronously rendering), it says the `QWindow`-based `QOffscreenSurface` are not allowed to exist outside the gui thread;
- When doing this in the main (GUI) thread, it says the `QOpenGLContext` is invalid.

So my questions are:

- Should I do the **offscreen** and **onscreen** work in the same GUI thread or not?
- What is the best way of communicating and sharing resources between the **offscreen** and **onscreen** parts?

A brief actual code example doing a simple rendering work (say, draw a triangle via shading language) will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `QOpenGLContext *main_ctx` is the context that was created by `QOpenGLWidget` for actual rendering, you can create another context `ctx` in any thread and make it share textures and buffers with the first one:

```
ctx = std::make_unique<QOpenGLContext>();
ctx->setFormat(main_ctx->format());
ctx->setShareContext(main_ctx);
ctx->create();
```

I don't think that `QOffscreenSurface` must be a `QWindow`-based.

```
offscreen_surface = std::make_unique<QOffscreenSurface>();
offscreen_surface->setFormat(ctx->format());
offscreen_surface->create();
ctx->makeCurrent(offscreen_surface);
```

Then create a `QOpenGLFramebufferObject` and render into it from the second context (second thread).

Then use its texture in the main context: `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo->texture());`. Maybe there is a need for some synchronization when doing this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What about multiple *offscreen* parts (in multiple threads), whose rendering results will be displayed in the same *onscreen* part in turn by some rules? Should their `ctx`s all share the same `main_ctx`? If multiple `fbo`s (from multiple *offscreen* parts) are then used, will they overlap each other? or will multiple `fbo->texture()`s return the same value? If so, how to avoid it? I don't quite familiar with the mechanism of `fbo` and texture.

Comment: It's not like "share the same main_ctx", because all shared contexts have equal rights: they share share textures, shaders, and other OpenGL resources. About FBOs: it seems that for each FBO Qt creates a separate texture to use.

Comment: Thanks again for you kind help! With your suggestions, I've tried to transfer the texture id `unit` from the FBO (*offscreen* part) to `QOpenGLTexture` (*onscreen* part), it didn't display the desired texture. I think the reason might be the unfamiliarity to the use of `QOpenGLTexture` with FBO. The document of Qt5.7 says that one can render **TO** texture and also render **WITH** texture. Is there any simple example about these two usages. (That might be another question, should I launch a new post?)

Comment: Make another question, so there would be a space to show the code with `QOpenGLFramebufferObject` that doesn't work. Then someone may fix the code if that code is a sufficiently self-contained example.

Comment: A new question ([this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39295154/render-to-and-with-texture-using-qopengltexture-and-qopenglframebufferobject)) has been posted. Thank you very much!