# How to create QOffscreenSurface with alpha?

Tags: qt, qt6, qtopengl

Found an [example of offscreen rendering in QT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59338015/minimal-opengl-offscreen-rendering-using-qt) (there is a working code in Update 1).

But was unable to make it support alpha, see the code below:

```
    QSurfaceFormat surfaceFormat;
    surfaceFormat.setColorSpace(QSurfaceFormat::ColorSpace::sRGBColorSpace);
    surfaceFormat.setRenderableType(QSurfaceFormat::RenderableType::OpenGL);
    surfaceFormat.setMajorVersion(4);
    surfaceFormat.setMinorVersion(3);
    surfaceFormat.setAlphaBufferSize(8);

    if (surfaceFormat.hasAlpha())
    {
        qInfo() << "The surface has alpha.";
    }
    else
    {
        qInfo() << "The surface does not have alpha.";
    }
```

it always prints "The surface has alpha." but my offscreen rendering works without alpha or saying more exactly I am getting a strange effect, the transparent pixels becomes white while the background is black:

[image]

compare it with the original image without transparency:

[image]

the difference is `vec4(fragColor, 0.5)` and `vec4(fragColor, 1.0)` in the fragment shader:

```
program.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment,
                               "#version 330\r\n"
                               "in vec3 fragColor;\n"
                               "out vec4 color;\n"
                               "void main() {\n"
                               "    color = vec4(fragColor, 1.0);\n"
                               "}\n"
                               );
```

Is there some other option I can set?

My environment: Windows 10, MSVC 2019, QT 6.2.

**EDIT1:**

Did some further experimentation and added the following before rendering the triangle:

```
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD);
        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

and got white background:

[image]

with `glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0.5)` I got gray:

[image]

Comment: There is probably a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49688111/offscreen-rendering-with-qoffscreensurface-qpainter-with-alpha-pen-color-faili

Comment: they are both black...

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie it can be white also, see EDIT1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image viewer displays your image on a white background so you see white or gray. With `glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1)` you will see a transparent triangle on a black background:

```
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD);
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

but resulting triangle will be partially transparent, so white image viewer background will be partially visible under the triangle.