# How to do (dynamic) offscreen render with QOffscreenSurface in Qt5 correctly?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qopenglfunctions

I am try to do some offscreen rendering jobs in Qt5.3 and I want to use `QOpenGLFramebufferObject::toImage` to output each pictures(I want to output a few pictures when render() draws different things).

Following the instructions of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221730/do-offscreen-renderopengl-with-qt5), I succeeded in offscreen rendering my first pic and outputing it. So to future on, I write an example as the following code and here is [a package in Google](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i1IvKocU6G2rFq6J_K4Pqxi2Hhc_eTQh/view?usp=sharing). I can get the first fbo content(and its output file correctly, but from the second time, the fbo was not re-render() and it always output the same pictures).
So I want to know what should I do after I finish one time offscreen render to make sure the next time would be correct in qt? Or is there anyone could tell me how to set animation correctly in `QOffscreenSurface`?

**qtestofffscreen.h:**

```
#ifndef QTESTOFFSCREEN_H
#define QTESTOFFSCREEN_H

#include <QOffscreenSurface>
#include <QWindow>
#include <QtGui/QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core>
#include <QImage>
#include <QGLFramebufferObject>
#include <QOpenGLPaintDevice>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QMutexLocker>

class QTestOffScreen : public QOffscreenSurface,
                   protected QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit QTestOffScreen(
        QScreen* targetScreen = nullptr,
        const QSize& size = QSize (1, 1));
~QTestOffScreen();

virtual void render();
virtual void initialize();
void renderNow();
void setAnimating(bool animating);

bool event(QEvent *) override;

void renderLater();
int  counts;

private:
QGLFramebufferObject *fbo;
bool m_animating;
bool m_update_pending;

QOpenGLContext *m_context;
QOpenGLPaintDevice *m_device;

QSize m_size;

QMutex mutex;

signals:
void doneImg(int index);
};

#endif // QTESTOFFSCREEN_H
```

**qtestofffscreen.cpp:**

```
#include "qtestoffscreen.h"
#include <QTime>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QOpenGLFramebufferObject>

QTestOffScreen::QTestOffScreen(QScreen *targetScreen,
                               const QSize &size):
    QOffscreenSurface(targetScreen),
    m_size(size),
    fbo(Q_NULLPTR),
    m_context(Q_NULLPTR),
    m_device(Q_NULLPTR),
    counts(100)
{
    requestedFormat().setVersion(3,3);
    setFormat(requestedFormat());
    create();

    m_context = new QOpenGLContext(this);
    m_context->setFormat(format());

    if (m_context->create())
    {
        m_context->makeCurrent(this);
        m_context->functions()->initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    }else
    {
        delete m_context;
        m_context = Q_NULLPTR;
        throw ("Still wrong here");
    }

    //To make sure m_context was initialized
    //in first time entering renderNow()
    delete m_context;
    m_context = Q_NULLPTR;
}

QTestOffScreen::~QTestOffScreen()
{
    delete m_context;
    delete m_device;
    if (fbo)
        delete fbo;
}

void QTestOffScreen::render()
{
    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT
          | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT
          | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT
          | GL_TEXTURE_BIT);

    glViewport(0,0,1920,1080);
    glOrtho(0,1920,0,1080,0,1);

    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);

    float tmp = float(qrand()%1000);
    float count = (float)counts * 10.0f;

    glLineWidth(3.0f);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        glVertex2f(count ,count );
        glVertex2f(count + 100,count);
        glVertex2f(count + 50,count + 100);
    glEnd();

    qDebug()<<QString("current tmp is %1").arg(count);

}

void QTestOffScreen::initialize()
{

    if (!fbo)
    {
        fbo = new QGLFramebufferObject(1920,1080,GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }

    fbo->bind();
}

void QTestOffScreen::renderNow()
{
    bool needsInitialize = false;
    if (!m_context)
    {
        m_context = new QOpenGLContext(this);
        m_context->setFormat(requestedFormat());
        m_context->create();

        if (m_context->isValid())
        {
            qDebug()<<"Right Here when creating m_context in renderNow";
        }

        needsInitialize = true;
    }

    if ( !m_context->makeCurrent(this) )
    {
        qDebug()<<"This fails in makeCurrent";
    }

    if (needsInitialize)
    {
        initializeOpenGLFunctions();
        initialize();
    }

        render();

        qDebug()<<counts;
        counts--;
        fbo->toImage().save(QString::number(counts) + QString(".png"));


    m_context->doneCurrent();

    if (counts >= 0)
    {
        m_update_pending = false;
        emit doneImg(counts);
    }
}

void QTestOffScreen::setAnimating(bool animating)
{
    m_animating = animating;

    m_update_pending = false;

    if (m_animating)
        renderLater();
}

bool QTestOffScreen::event(QEvent *event)
{
    switch (event->type())
    {
    case QEvent::UpdateRequest:
        m_update_pending = true;
        renderNow();
        return true;
    default:
        return QOffscreenSurface::event(event);
    }
}

void QTestOffScreen::renderLater()
{
    if (!m_update_pending)
    {
        m_update_pending = true;
        QCoreApplication::postEvent(this,new QEvent(QEvent::UpdateRequest));
    }
}

void QTestOffScreen::generateImg(QImage *tmp_img_pointer)
{
    GLint viewPort[4]={0};
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT,viewPort);

    int win_width,win_height;
    win_width = 1920;
    win_height = 1080;

    GLubyte *colorArr=new GLubyte[win_width*win_height*3];

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glReadBuffer (GL_FRONT);

    int tmp_x,tmp_y;
    tmp_x = 0;
    tmp_y = 0;

    glReadPixels(tmp_x,tmp_y,win_width,win_height,
                 GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,colorArr);

    int winrows = tmp_img_pointer->height();
    int wincols = tmp_img_pointer->width ();


    for(int ii=0; ii < winrows * wincols * 3; ii ++)
    {
        if((colorArr[ii] <0)|(colorArr[ii] >255))
        { colorArr[ii] = 255; }
    }


    for(int j=0;j<winrows;j++)
        for(int i=0;i<wincols;i++)
        {
            int index=(j*wincols+i)*3;
            QRgb value=qRgb(colorArr[index+2],
                            colorArr[index+1],
                            colorArr[index  ]);
            tmp_img_pointer->setPixel(i,winrows-j-1,value);
        }
    delete colorArr;
}
```

**mainwindow.h:**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "qtestoffscreen.h"
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    QTestOffScreen *scr;

private slots:
    void ReceiveCurrentIndex(int);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setSamples(1);
    format.setRenderableType(QSurfaceFormat::OpenGL);

    scr = new QTestOffScreen();

    connect(scr,SIGNAL(doneImg(int)),this,SLOT(ReceiveCurrentIndex(int)));

    scr->setFormat(format);

    scr->setAnimating(true);//Start rendering animation here.

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::ReceiveCurrentIndex(int)
{
    Sleep(100);

    scr->renderLater();
}
```

Comment: You need to bind the `fbo` before rendering and release it before you grab the image. Currently you only bind it once (through `initialize`) .

Comment: @Botje Thanks firstly and I changed my code like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FRGbtjR6q6SQGvq614WIgaATNCNz9sSX/view?usp=sharing) but it didn't work ,I believe it still has some problems in QOpenGL context setting stuffs.